Notation of Haar measure
Quick question about the notation of Haar measures:
Consider the (multiplicative) group $G = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
y & x \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}  |\ x,y\in \mathbb{R}, \ y>0\}$. I read that the left-invariant Haar measure is given by $d \mu_{L} = y^{-2}dxdy$.
Now my question is how do you read that equality, what is $\mu_{L}(S)$ for some Borel-Set S?

$\mu_L(S)=\int_W y^{-2}dxdy$ where $W={(x,y): \begin{pmatrix}
x & y \
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \in S}$

Isn't it rather $x>0$ in your definition of $G$?

And isn't the Haar measure rather $\frac1xdxdy$?

Ur right I mixed up the x and y. Let me edit this.

So if I read the Haar measure on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is given by $d\mu = |det(A)|^{-n}  d\lambda(A)$ , this just means that $\mu(S) = \int_S  |det(A)|^{-n}  d\lambda(A)$, correct? I denote by $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$
